# Update Statement not updating when run from a stored procedure, but works perfectly when run manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

My first post here, so please be gentle with me :)

I have a stored procedure with which I take some source data, do some manipulation, run some update statements on it and then put the data into our main data table (I guess you could say its an ETL). The problem I have is some of the update statements I've written don't seem to have worked when the procedure has run, however, if I run them manually in a seperate query window they work perfectly.There are technically two parts to the update statement and one part updates and the other fails, which adds further complication to my trouble.

The snippet of code for the update is as follows:

```
UPDATE Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect
SET    pCommissionValue = (SELECT Commission
                           FROM   dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission
                           WHERE  Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect.pMRC BETWEEN BaseMRC AND HighMRC),
       pMRCBand = (SELECT MRCBand
                   FROM   dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission
                   WHERE  Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect.pMRC BETWEEN BaseMRC AND HighMRC)
WHERE  pMapID = 'iPhone'
```

The code updates 2 columns in my source table where the MRC of the record falls between the base and high mrc. Commission is the value which is not updating, however MRCBand updates correctly.

The MappingiPhoneCommission table has the following columns:

- BaseMRC
- HighMRC
- Commission
- MRCBand

If anyone could shed any light onto why this would fail in the stored procedure but run fine in a new query window I would be most appreciative.

If you require any further information please let me know and i will try to supply what is needed.

Kind Regards
Tony

Comment: The sub-query to update pCommissionValue ALWAYS returns a single value?

Comment: When you run your query outside the stored procedure, do you only run the UPDATE statement, or everything which is in that stored procedure?

Comment: If i run the entire procedure not as a proc, the column doesnt update, but only running the code i posted, does work.   The mapping table has essentially the following 0,25,5,Bronze;26,35,7,Silver;36,99999,9,Gold.  These are fictional records but what the statement does is take the MRC value of the record, find out which range of base and high MRC it fits and returns the commision value and MRCBand.  for example if the record MRC was 35, the commission would be 7 and the MRCBand silver.

Comment: Do you get any error? How are you sure that UPDATE is the culprit? Can you paste the entire SP?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for this code to act differently in a stored procedure, so I would assume the stored procedure makes a change in the data before the update. I would advise adding some checks to your stored procedure to see what the actual data at runtime is. You might start adding the following just before the update:

```
SELECT * FROM Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect WHERE  pMapID = 'iPhone'
SELECT Commission FROM dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission, Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect
WHERE Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect.pMRC BETWEEN dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission.BaseMRC AND dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission.HighMRC
SELECT MRCBand FROM dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission, Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect
WHERE Prod_DDb.dbo.DataLoadTeleconnect.pMRC BETWEEN dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission.BaseMRC AND dbo.MappingiPhoneCommission.HighMRC
```

Comment: Hi All,  I have solved the issue.  What I had was another update statement which came in later which kind of over wrote my above statement.  I have solved this by using inner joins.  Thank you all for your thoughts and pointers everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored proc does not have a try catch block, then put one in. Likely the SP is failing just above this update which is why it doesn;t happen, without a trycatch block, you are probably not rolling back the whole transaction or bubbling up the actual error.

Answer (score -3):

you can use FOR loop calling the columns in select statement and then updating the columns. this will help you out.

Comment: This is in sql so I assume you mean running it in a cursor, while loop etc. Even if that's the case, this won't really solve OP's problem